# Сайт некорректно работает Wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, css

Здравствуйте. Перенес сайт на на новый домен. Сайт стал некорректно работать. Сайты находятся на одном сервере. Дело в том, что использую вордпресс, на главной странице совершается автоматическая загрузка следующих страниц (jquery) при скроллинг вниз,проблема в том что после переноса на новый домен загрузка страниц не останавливается т.е. после загрузке последней страницы загружается опять первая страница и так повторяется до бесконечности. Сайт на локалке работает нормально и на другом домене работал но на новом как то не работает 2 раза перезагружал сайт на сервер.

В чем может быть проблема? Уже второй день не понимаю в чем проблема. Спасибо за внимание.

*Обновление*

`.htaccess`:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: rewrite rules не настроены

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв. Вы имели ввиду .htaccess? Обновлил вопрос, добавил .htaccess

Comment: php и javscript дозагрузки страницы вставь в вопрос. Или дай ссылку на сайт.